# array from php to jquery via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a javascript that contacts a php page which gets some data from a database and save it in an array.

I want to take that array and loop it out with jquery.

The array looks like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
  [1] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
  [2] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
  [3] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
  [4] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
  [5] => Array ( [image] => article_list1.png [title] => Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent ) 
);
```

Comment: I'd simply convert the Array to JSON and send the JSON string to the client. I think jQuery can deserialize JSON without an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to json_encode the array and then echo the result out to the JavaScript/jQuery:

[json_encode PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Here is the PHP [php demo](http://codepad.org/kPKZkTD4)

```
<?php
$myarray = Array ( 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ), 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ), 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ), 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ), 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ), 
  Array ( 'image' => 'article_list1.png', 'title' => 'Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent' ) 
);

echo json_encode($myarray);
?>
```

This should give you something like this:

```
[{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"}]
```

and to access it using jQuery [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2gr2V/):

```
var myJson = '[{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"},{"image":"article_list1.png","title":"Everyone involved in OMS in Ghent"}]';
myJson = JSON.parse(myJson);
for(var i=0; i<myJson.length; i++)
    console.log(myJson[i].image+ ' ' + myJson[i].title);
```

Comment: K. and how do I turn that into an array in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use php To print that array as a js list. Or export it via json.